# How to import name through classes

Tags: python, class

So I am trying to learn how to send values between two classes and I  have started to get stuck into sending a value from one class to another. The code looks like:

Class 1

```
from proxymanager import ProxyManager

proxy_manager = ProxyManager('proxies.txt')


class Logger:

    def __init__(self, lock=multiprocessing.Lock()):
        self.logger_lock = lock
        colorama.init()

    def get_random_proxy(self):
        proxy = proxy_manager.random_proxy().get_dict()
        return proxy
```

Class 2

```
from utils import Logger

logger = Logger()

def main():
    print(logger.get_random_proxy)
```

The issue I am standing on right now is that whenever I try to print out `print(logger.get_random_proxy)` I am getting a follow error of : `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_random_proxy' from 'utils'` and I have trying to figure out what is the issue but I have been stuck and I am here to ask you guys what am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: the file contain your Logger class need to name utils.py, are you sure it correct?

Comment: ?! You must be trying to do `from utils import get_random_proxy` somewhere in your code. I don't think it's possible for the code in the post to raise this error.

Comment: Yes, the class 1 is named utils.py, the second class is named test.py :) @LeHoangGiang

Comment: @ForceBru Thats what confused me. I am not having `from utils import Logger, get_random_proxy` so I am not sure how it can raise me that error when I just have the code that is showed here :/

Comment: Cannot reproduce **that** error with **that** code...

Comment: Cannot reproduce too. You must be trying to import `get_random_proxy` from `utils` or something like that. You can copy this code to a new empty directory and run it to see that no error is being raised

Comment: You guys are actually true hmm.. This is very odd. But in thath case, how could I in that case make it work through those two classes because even if I copy the code in a new empty directory it doesn't print anything.